# Multi Maven Module Spring MVC Project to Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, docker, spring-boot

I've been doing a lot of research before I posted here, and I wanted to get an opinion on whether I should create a new Spring Boot project, and use a multi-maven structure ... or, should I convert my current maven multi-module Spring MVC RESTful project to Spring Boot.

We want a Spring Boot project because it might be easier to use Docker then.
We really, want this Spring MVC RESTful back-end in a Docker container, but all the examples we find involve using Spring Boot and Docker.

So, the project has a structure like this:

```
parent pom.xml 
   Entity 
   - basic Spring Project with Hibernate entities
   - has a myproject-entity-context.xml as the Spring application context
   - has the database and transactions configured in the context
   - translates to a JAR file
   - has its own pom.xml and can be built independently
   DAO
   - basic Spring project with Data Access crud Objects
   - has it's own myproject-dao-context.xml file
   - inherits from the myproject-entity-context.xml
   - pulls in the myproject-entity.jar file in the pom.xml
   - translates to a JAR file
   - has its own pom.xml so this DAO can be built provided the entity.jar is built
   - obviously this layer does all the database work
   - very much init tested
    Service (Business Services)
   - basic Spring project with Transactional Business Services
   - one business service can call mutltiple DAO's 
   - has it's own myproject-service-context.xml file
   - inherits from the myproject-dao-context.xml
   - pulls in the myproject-dao.jar file in the pom.xml
   - translates to a JAR file
   - has its own pom.xml so this Service can be built, provided the DAO is built first
   - obviously this layer does all the business services work
   - very much init tested
   Web-Services
   - basic Spring Web-App project that compiles to WAR
   - has all the Controllers which stores all the endpoints
   - has it's own myproject-ws-context.xml file
   - inherits from the myproject-service-context.xml
   - pulls in the myproject-service.jar file in the pom.xml
   - translates to a WAR file
   - has its own pom.xml so these Web-Services can be built, provided the myproject-service.JAR is built first
   - obviously this layer does all RESTful end-points which call 1 business service
   - very much init tested
```

Our Spring MVC RESTful back-end also uses Spring Env Profiles, and we have one profile which reads in an external env.properties file.

We also use Spring Security 4.0 to secure the RESTful endpoints.

We want to put this app in a Docker container?  But all the documentation works with Spring Boot, so we can either add Spring Boot to this existing project, but I don't know how ... or it might be easier to start with a new Spring Boot project and then take my existing code and put that into the new Spring Boot project.   I don't which is easier, or which is harder?

Do we even need Spring Boot to put this app into a Docker Container?

Any help would be much appreciated, and if I need to, I can add more information here as I need to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Spring Boot to deploy your app in a Docker container. There are several strategies you could follow.

**DOWNLOADING THE BINARIES TO THE CONTAINER (THE MOST USUAL)**:

you have your .war artifact deployed to a nexus repository. From there, starting from a server image you download the artifact, storing it in the deployment folder of the server.

For instance in **Wildfly** you could do something like this:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly

EXPOSE 8080

RUN curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -f http://${NEXUS_REPOSITORY_URL}?r=${REPOSITORY}&g=${GROUP_ID}&a=${ARTIFACT}&p=war&v=${VERSION} -o /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war
```

For **Tomcat**:

```
FROM tomcat

EXPOSE 8080

RUN curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -f http://${NEXUS_REPOSITORY_URL}?r=${REPOSITORY}&g=${GROUP_ID}&a=${ARTIFACT}&p=war&v=${VERSION} -o /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

**GENERATING THE BINARY IN THE CONTAINER (MORE CUMBERSOME):**

You can apt-get git, checkout a repository branch(master, tag or whatever), mvn package it to generate the war and finally copy it to the deployment file.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  "There are many strategies you could follow ..."   Unfortunately, I don't know what any of those strategies are, and what the pro's/con's of those strategies are.   I've been trying to find a place where that is documented, and I haven't had much luck.  So, I'll be going to quite a few docker meetups in my local area to try and become more knowledgeable on Docker.   Thanks for the help again.